# « Pour » ou « de » se déplacer

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Quelle phrase est correcte?

> - A. Le métro est le moyen de transport le plus rapide **pour** se déplacer à Londres

ou

> - B. Le métro est le moyen de transport le plus rapide **de** se déplacer à Londres

Je pense que A. est correcte, mais je ne suis pas sûr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A est correct, B est incorrect. On peut aussi dire "le moyen le plus rapide de se déplacer". On ne peut juste pas utiliser "de" deux fois dans l'expression "le moyen de".

Comment: merci beaucoup :)